# thingsboard Dashboard MQTT export to android studio

Tags: android, iot, thingsboard

making project IOT receiving data from ESP32 using MQTT protocol and send it to thingsboard to see dashboard but i need to see this dashboard on application android not the website of thingsboard
i need to know if it's possible to do it with community service? or i can only share the public link from thingsboard
thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a Mobile Application in Flutter (Android, iOS) which also works with ThingsBoard CE and can be customized:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/mobile/getting-started/